# Can I hit API endpoints from Kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have made dashboards for monitoring my services. But I also want to trigger the services again from the kibana only. I don't want another interface for that. Is that possible with Kibana?

I have created a GET endpoint which can trigger the service. But how can I integrate this in Kibana and solve this problem?

Comment: What you mean by trigger service ? Is it like you wanted to access elasticsearch apis ?

Comment: No I want to call third party APIs. Its like a start and stop button for a backend process. @AshishTiwari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such mechanism on Kibana where you can add button and on click you can trigger some third party API or services.